# How can I remove this error from my console?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I receive the following error:

```sh
Uncaught ReferenceError: notesObj is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (apps.js:14)
```

I could store the object earlier in the local storage and there was no error generated. But after the removal of the 'card' division after 'your notes' it is now difficult for me to remove the error.

```js
//shownotes();
//If user add a note, add it to the local storage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn')
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById('addTxt');
  let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notesObj.push(addTxt.value)
  localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addTxt.value = '';
  console.log(notesObj);
  shownotes();
})

function shownotes() {
  let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  let html = '';
  notesObj.forEach(function(element, index) {
    html += `<div class="card my-3 mx-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Notes ${index + 1}</h5>
                <p class='card-text'>${element}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success my-3">Add Notes</a>
                <buttom href="#" class="btn btn-danger my-3">Delete notes</button>
            </div>
        </div>`
  });
  let notesElm = document.getElementById('notes')
  if (notes.length != 0) {
    notesElm.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    notesElm.innerHTML = `Nothing to show! Use 'Add notes section above to add notes `
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Make notes!</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container my-3 text-center">
    <h1>Magic notes</h1>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Quick notes</h5>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
          <!-- <label for="floatingTextarea2">Add your notes here</label> -->
        </div>
        <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-3" id="addBtn">Add notes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h1 class="text-center">Your notes</h1>
  <hr>
  <div id="notes" class="row container-fluid">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think you should define a array value like this var noeObj = new Array();

Comment: I think you have a typo: no"d"esObj no"t"esObj

Comment: Change `nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);` to `notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);`

Comment: I am not seeing this error on my browser. Here is the [test link][1]. I can also see the notes array in the local storage. Also could you please give more clarity on this. 


  [1]: https://js-5kbkc5.stackblitz.io

Comment: if you write nodesObj and notesObj correctly test my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the code you provided, it appears to me that you try to use `nodesObj` before it was ever defined anywhere. I think you meant `notesObj`. Either define `nodesObj` like this, or fix the typo.

You may want to do something like

```
Now my java script code is from here.
var nodesObj = new Array(); // Declare the variable BEFORE using it anywhere.

console.log('This is the notes app.')
//shownotes();
//If user add a note, add it to the local storage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn')
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let addTxt = document.getElementById('addTxt');
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    notesObj.push(addTxt.value)
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    addTxt.value = '';
    console.log(notesObj);
    shownotes();
})

function shownotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    let html = '';
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
        html += `<div class="card my-3 mx-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Notes ${index + 1}</h5>
            <p class='card-text'>${element}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success my-3">Add Notes</a>
            <buttom href="#" class="btn btn-danger my-3">Delete notes</button>
        </div>
    </div>`
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById('notes')
    if (notes.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = `Nothing to show! Use 'Add notes section above to add notes `
    }
}
```

Comment: He is defining it in his if else blocks, but he has a typo in the else block

Answer (score 0):

you write somethings wrong
test it

```
console.log('This is the notes app.')
//shownotes();
//If user add a note, add it to the local storage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn')
var nodesObj = new Array();
var notesObj = new Array();
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let addTxt = document.getElementById('addTxt');
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    notesObj.push(addTxt.value)
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    addTxt.value = '';
    console.log(notesObj);
    shownotes();
})

function shownotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        nodesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    let html = '';
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
        html += `<div class="card my-3 mx-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Notes ${index + 1}</h5>
            <p class='card-text'>${element}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success my-3">Add Notes</a>
            <buttom href="#" class="btn btn-danger my-3">Delete notes</button>
        </div>
    </div>`
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById('notes')
    if (notes.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = `Nothing to show! Use 'Add notes section above to add notes `
    }
}
```